# three.js GLTFloader Geometry and Material

Tags: three.js

How do I see geometry and material with GLTFLoader in three.js? Right now it's a blank white page. Sorry this is my 2nd day on three.js, I don't think I understood completely on the manual.
https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>demo</title>
    <style>
        body {margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>

    <script>
        var renderer, scene, camera, myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: myCanvas, antialias: true });
        renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 300, 10000);
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.8);  
        var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        scene.add(light); 
        scene.add(light2);

        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('model.gltf', function (gltf) {
            scene.add(gltf.scene);
        });


        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors? I think your canvas needs a height and width to be visible. Instead of passing a canvas from the page into the renderer, perhaps try `document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement )`. And to be safe, make sure your model is visible on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/, in case it's a problem with the model.

Comment: OK. There're no errors, and the model is visible in the gltf viewer.

Comment: Were you able to find out how to apply a material for the loaded model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your camera near plane is super far away..  I also notice you don't position your camera initially.. it's probably starting inside the object..
or your object is too large or too small to see because it's behind the camera near clip plane..

try this:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(100,100,100);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
```

Comment: :))))))) IT WORKS! Thank you!